# Javascript regex validation for country name

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Did anyone use java script validation for country name? Or are there any jquery methods to do that.

Thank you.

Comment: Can there be a way for i18n validation too?

Comment: auto complete would be the way to go here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: In that case, could I add for different languages. This would be perfect for one language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be interested in existing web services such as [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/export/geonames-search.html) that allow you to search for an address (or simply a country) for checking purpose.